# My simple C program isn't compiling

Tags: c

I'm doing a small exercise for my C class and I'm getting difficulties I know shouldn't really be happening as these are supposed to take like 30 minutes max. Here is my program so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define LIMIT 1000000;

bool isPrime( int num ) {
    for ( int factor = 2; factor * factor <= num; factor++ )
      if ( num % factor == 0 )
        return false;

    return true;
  }

int main() {
  for ( int num = 2; num <= LIMIT; num++ ) {
    if ( isPrime( num ) ) {
      printf( num );
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
primes.c: In function “main”:
primes.c:14: error: expected expression before “;” token
primes.c:16: warning: passing argument 1 of “printf” makes pointer from integer without a cast
/usr/include/stdio.h:361: note: expected “const char * restrict” but argument is of type “int”
```

Comment: Remove the semicolon after `#define LIMIT 1000000`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As @[Inspired](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1062250/inspired) said there is an extra semicolon in the `LIMIT` macro definition, that semicolon will be expanded by the preprocessor making this line

```
for ( int num = 2; num <= LIMIT; num++ ) {
```

like this

```
for ( int num = 2; num <= LIMIT;; num++ ) {
                            /* ^^ 2 semicolons, now the num++ is extra */
```

but your program has yet another problem

```
printf(num);
```

will not work, `printf()` expects a format string and then the arguments so it should be

```
printf("%d\n", num);
```

read [this](http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?printf+3)

Answer (score 6):

You have an extra `;` in `#define LIMIT 1000000;`.

When handling `#define`, compiler just performs a text substitution: it replaces `LIMIT` with `1000000;`. So your `for` loop looks like

```
for (int num=2; num < 1000000 ;; num++) 
                              ^^
```

The second error happens because indeed `printf` expects the first argument to be a string (format string), not an integer. E.g. `printf("%d is prime.\n", num);` (`%d` is a placeholder for an integer value, and `\n` is end-of-line).

Comment: Wow, thanks. I'm used to Java. That took care of the error at line 14.

Answer (score 3):

No semi-colon after `LIMIT` define. Processor directives don't get them so it is literally copying `"100000;"` into the for loop.

First argument of printf should be format string `"%d"` so `printf("%d\n", num)`

Simple stuff you'll get used to (and still mess up when not thinking), but if you are just learning,  it looks great. Far better than my first C programs.